# Is it possible in VUE3 to use v-model as a computed property?

Tags: vuejs3, computed-properties

For example:

`<MyComponent v-model="thisComputed" />`

Where thisComputed is a computed property.

I do not know if it is possible. If is, then how?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the computed properties are readonly.

But you can provide your computed property with a setter. Check the Vue Docs: [Writable Computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#computed-caching-vs-methods)

Here is the way to create writable computed properties.

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
    
const thisComputed = computed({
  // getter
  get() {
    return something
  },
  // setter
  set(newValue) {
    do something
  }
})
</script>
```

### Playground

```js
const {
  createApp,
  computed,
  ref
} = Vue;

const App = {
  setup() {
    const someValue = ref('test')
    const thisComputed = computed({
      // getter
      get() {
        return someValue.value
      },
      // setter
      set(newValue) {
        someValue.value = newValue
      }
    })
    return {
      someValue,
      thisComputed
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="thisComputed" /><br/>
  <label>thisComputed:</label> {{thisComputed}}<br/>
  <label>someValue:</label> {{someValue}}<br/>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```